# hide image when image clicked

Tags: javascript, html

This should be so simple but there's no proper solutions that allow this on the image.

I have this code...

```html
<div class="message">
   <div class="message-container">
      <div class="messageimg">
         <!-- Message Img -->
         <img class="messageimg" src="/message.png" alt="message"></a>
      </div>
   </div>
```

I don't want a button or anything else like that. I just want the user to click the image and then it be gone.

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like this, also i strongly advise separating javascript from html

```html
<p onclick="this.style.display='none'">imageElt</p>
```

a bit cleaner version would be :

```js
myimg.addEventListener("click",()=>{myimg.style.display="none";});
```

```html
<p id="myimg">imgElt</p>
```

Comment: Incredible, I wanted something simple because the image doesn't need to come back. Thank you

Comment: Glad you provided an event listener as an alternative. I hate inline JS and avoid it whenever possible.